# What's the default Jsoup User Agent string?

Tags: android, jsoup

If I don't call `userAgent()` to set the user agent string for Jsoup, what's the default user agent string Jsoup uses?

```
Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com/").get();
```

I am using Jsoup in an Android app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Jsoup, the user agent is the version of Java. Trying this code on desktop Java (can't try on android right now):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.useragentstring.com/").get();
System.out.println(doc.title());
```

Results in:

```
UserAgentString.com - Java version 1.8.0_05
```

So on Android it would result in something similar.
This is because Jsoup does not define a user agent itself, but it just uses what the underlying Java `HttpUrlConnection` and `Connection` class uses.

So, it's probably best to set the Jsoup user agent in code, always.

Comment: I got 'UserAgentString.com - Galaxy' from an Android emulator using your code.

Comment: The full string is 'Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.1; Google Galaxy Nexus - 4.1.1 - API 16 - 720x1280 Build/JRO03S)'.